# How to do title on top of the marker in Google Maps javascript API

Tags: javascript, google-maps, meteor, google-maps-api-3

How do I draw a title on top of marker in google map.I can use markerwithlabel.js but is there an API i can use straight from google map javascript API to achieve this?

[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21861585/google-maps-api-marker-tooltip

Comment: its different i need a title, the solution is a infowindow

Comment: How is this possible on android for custom OSM based map?